# Giving the Blog Administration installation the same look as the rest of the sidebar items

Tags: css

At this [test position](http://www.test.webitry.net) there is a Sidebar with a Blog Administration box installed. I want the CSS to gave it the same layout as the boxes above it. The controlling css is described in the #mainmenu as I have moved this from the top of the blog when I installed the main site navigation. No matter what I do I cannot get it to match the other items in the sidebar!

See image attached.!
[image]

Comment: For the log of Gove! Dont use tables for layouts!

Comment: But the script came with a table layout!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap <li> elements inside an <ul>, like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks @Dbugger. Installed the <ul>....</ul> tags to each of the <li></li> tags in the .php page. It looks like this:                        if($lstatus == "on") {
 $mainlinks .= "<ul><li><a href=\"index.php\">Blog $lang[37]Page</a></li></ul> \n";                                                      Maybe this is being pickie, but what might be causing the Double space between the links in the Blog Administration panel?